# Where are Python dylibs installed on the Mac?

Tags: python, macos, dylib

On Mac OSX 10.6.4 where do you install dynamic libraries (dylib) so Python 2.6.1 can import them? I've tried placing them in /usr/local/lib and usr/localbin and /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages but none of these locations have worked. The library I'm trying to install is libevecache.dylib a library to access cache files for Eve-Online.

Answer (score 0):

Anywhere in your `$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` should work for compiled library files; you can also try setting `$PYTHONPATH` / `sys.path`.

Comment: Both environment variables were unset but after exporting them with the dir /usr/local/lib did not change anything. Python is still giving this error: ImportError: No module named evecache

Answer (score 0):

Run the included `setup.py` file. You should *never* try to copy things into place manually; it'll lead to disaster, especially in situations involving `pip` or `easy_install`.